# Optional IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

```
public Optional<Student> findStudent(String name, String` surname,String nickname)
         {

    try {

       return repository.findOne(predicates.hasSpecifications(name, String surname,nickname));

    } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e) {

        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

the method findOne() throws **IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException** if more than one entry is found for the predicate inside of it. Is this the best way to handle the exception thrown? or should the caller handle the exception using something like: optional.orElseThrow()... but this method only handles **NoSuchElementException** (if no value is present) and not **IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException**  (If more than 1 RESULT)...

Any ideas guys?

Comment: The question is what do **you** want to happen if the query yields more than one result?

Comment: tell the user that there is more than one result @Chaosfire

Comment: I would switch to a method returning a List and return correct response based on the size then. I see no benefit in dealing with exceptions just for this.

Comment: @Chaosfire but shouldn't unchecked exceptions not caused by a programming error be caught and handled? For example in my case if the DB has more than 1 entry for the same Student it's not a programming problem but a external database issue... I see many opinions about this but i'm unsure what to do...

Comment: This is opinion, but since you have to somehow deal with incorrect data in db, no point in dealing with exceptions at all. That's why i proposed switching to a method, which returns a list and does not throw exceptions for more than 1 result. For 1 result in list, return the result, for other (0 or more than 1) return appropriate message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this would be the best way to do it.

I'm assuming hasSpecifications is a custom method which returns the id you wish to use to index the database
The thing is "findOne" and "hasSpecifications" are two methods independent of each other.
When we talk about abstraction, in methods then the only things that matter are their input parameters, the return values and the errors that may or may not be thrown.

This means "findOne" only cares about what "hasSpecifications" evaluates to. If there is an error or exception thrown while "hasSpecifications" is still executing then this error abruptly terminates the program (unless caught) and findOne wont even be evaluated (Because it was waiting for the id). A NoSuchElementException cannot be thrown because findOne hadn't started executing yet.

So since it's a custom method, the error handling has to be done by you, as you just did.

To make it more obvious extract predicates.hasSpecifications into a variable on a preceeding line and then place the variable in "findOne"